# asp.net Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException "no validator found" after logging in through ADFS

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, single-sign-on, adfs

I am working on setting up a website that uses ADFS for Single Sign-On, following the instructions found [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/).  everything is set up on both the client site and the adfs server, but after logging in, I receive this error.

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException: no validator found
```

I've been reading documentation on Microsoft's IdentityModel, but I can't find anything that would cause such an error nor have I found anyone else with a similar problem.

This has me stumped, and any information that can help me figure this out would be appreciated.

EDIT: This is what the startup class looks like

```
    public partial class Startup
{
    private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
            });
    }
}
```

and this is what's on the web.config

```
<configuration>


 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:ADFSMetadata" value="https://XXX.*DOMAIN*.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Wtrealm" value="*REALM*" />

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.1.0" newVersion="5.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.1.0" newVersion="5.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.1.0" newVersion="5.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.1.0" newVersion="5.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.1.0" newVersion="5.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.1.0" newVersion="5.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

This is the full Stack Trace as well:

```
    [SecurityTokenException: no validator found]
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1f.MoveNext() +4732
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1f.MoveNext() +4748
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +817
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +329
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +194
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +768
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +194
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +184
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +117
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +365
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

Comment: Some code for context would be of help!

Comment: Added. If there's any other code that is needed, please let me know.

Comment: I am getting the same with windows auth with Identity Server 3.

Answer (score 0):

Set `EncryptClaims` to `False` on ADFS Server. Seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue in .NET8, but I couldn't change the ADFS Server since it's not managed by me directly, I resolved it by changing the OnSecurityTokenReceived Event and validating the token manually.
Example in Program.cs:

```
const string COOKIE_NAME = "CookieName";
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddWsFederation(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnSecurityTokenReceived = CustomSAMLTokenValidation(options);
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.CallbackPath = "/loginadfs";
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://myadfs.server.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml";
    options.Wtrealm = "https://myapp.example.com";
}).AddCookie((x) =>
{
    x.Cookie.Name = COOKIE_NAME;
    x.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    x.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    x.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    x.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

The custom validation can be done like this:
!!Note that: in wsFederationConfiguration there all the information (including or the enc and sign keys) needed to decrypt and validate the token:

```
static Func<SecurityTokenReceivedContext, Task> CustomSAMLTokenValidation(WsFederationOptions options)
{
    return async context =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnSecurityTokenReceived");

        var token = context.ProtocolMessage.GetToken();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            context.Fail("No token found.");
            return;
        }
        var handler = options.TokenHandlers.OfType<SamlSecurityTokenHandler>().First();

        var WsConfiguration = await options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        // Validate the SAML token
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = options.Wtrealm,
            ValidIssuer = WsConfiguration.Issuer,
            IssuerSigningKeys = WsConfiguration.SigningKeys,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        };

        try
        {
            var claims = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
            // Add the claims from the SAML token to the current principal or any additional claims
            context.Principal = claims;
            context.Success();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            context.Fail(ex);
        }
        return;
    };
}
```